# References for excess power of a Chi-Squared test

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

I am working on an example for Benford's law and using UK house numbers I get the following empirical and theoretical distribution for the first digits.
[image: Graphical comparison of the distributions]
Although the graphical inspection clearly shows that the numbers do conform to Benford's law quite perfectly. I can safely reject the null hypothesis that both distributions are the same, which is of course caused by the large sample size of 93,087 house numbers.

```
Pearson's Chi-squared test
X-squared = 106, df = 8, p-value <2e-16
```

I know that this is caused by the large sample size and I find some information for that in Nigrini (2012: p. 154)[Google Book Link](https://books.google.de/books?id=Bh5Vr_I1NZoC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=excess%20power%20problem%20chi%20square%20test&source=bl&ots=qbi9bryxQj&sig=PpFnRnVgALmyZCKWykw4mXUv3Gs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN5u61vfDZAhUQJ1AKHQ5CD_cQ6AEIXzAF#v=onepage&q=excess%20power%20problem%20chi%20square%20test&f=false)

I would like to know if there are some further references discussing this problem. Perhaps also some additional reference for the hypotheses raised by Nigrini that this starts with sample sizes larger than 5,000.

Answer (score 1):

Chi-squared seems inappropriate to your aim, which is to determine if there is a strong relationship between your model and your data. Chi squared tests for differences, not similarity nor association so is the inverse of your needs. You cannot 'prove' a null hypothesis, only fail to reject it or state that you have a defined level of confidence it does not apply. Many articles and discussion boards cover this topic extensively, resources I found invaluable when I began to understand this aspect of statistical inference (regretfully more years into my research career than I care to admit, it took me a lot of head aches and diving deeper than I ever wished)

https://www.researchgate.net/post/how_to_interpret_P_values
http://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/what-a-p-value-tells-you-about-statistical-data/
http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/how-to-correctly-interpret-p-values
https://academic.oup.com/jnci/article/99/4/332/2522393

This means that a low p value for your Chi Square test would be interpreted that the probability of there being zero difference between your proposed distribution and you observed distribution is very low. A high p-value would be interpreted as the differences between the distributions could arise from random chance.

Neither of these interpretations are identical to 'graphical inspection clearly shows that the numbers do conform to Benford's law quite perfectly'. This phrase suggests that you wish to demonstrate concordance/equivalence or association between your expected and observed data. This suggests that the hypothesis you wish to falsify is 'the observed data is equivalent to Benford's law within a confidence interval of X'.

Correlation would be a more relevant statistic and will tell you the strength of agreement between your model and the data. $ R^2 $ will tell you the proportion of your data that can be explained by your model. There will be some that isn't, which suggests that some other factors are perturbing the data slightly away from your ideal model. Your observed data will not be Benfords law plus true random noise, instead it will be Benford's law plus other subtle but real effects that cause small but real deviances. Using a big sample number gives you greater power for detecting these non-random subtle effects. Whether those subtle deviances are big enough to matter will be handled by $R^2$.

Whether it is worth examining the additional factors that mean your data deviates from the model will depend on $ R^2 $, which I suspect will be large. It will come down to matter of practical significance rather than statistical significance.

It is not that chi squared is over powered, I suggest it is answering a different question to what you want.

Comment: It's not a comparsion between a model and data. It's a comparison between an expected distribution and an empirical observable distribution. I think that's exactly the question to answer with a Chi-Square test.I don't see how there should be any relation to correlation or anything related to a model, because that's not what I am trying to show.

Comment: In your case you have modelled your expected distribution using a model (Benford distribution). An expected distribution is a model by definition. It may be an empirically derived one (i.e. a counted distribution of a comparator population), but the point is that you use that to model the population of interest. Could you please spell out the exact null hypothesis that you wish to test so that the answer can be tailored. 'Although the graphical inspection clearly shows that the numbers do conform to Benford's law quite perfectly' is a visual description of the correlation.

Comment: What Chi squared is measuring is the residual after you account for the expected distribution (so you would plot the difference between the model (which is what your expected distribution is) and the data on the Y axis.  If you plot confidence intervals on such a difference plot then you will have a visual approximation of the Chi-square. I advise you to update your question with this new figure and also to add confidence intervals at each point in the existing figure. That way I can tailor the answer better to your data.

Comment: Well, yes, but in my opinion you are making it overly complicated. Since this is basically just the normal Chi-squared test for the goodness-of-fit with the null hypothesis that the observed frequency distribution is the same as the theoretical distribution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Definition

Comment: I don't know how to put it any simpler than Chi Squared is not testing the same thing as your eyeballs when you make the statement 'Although the graphical inspection clearly shows that the numbers do conform to Benford's law quite perfectly'. It is an inappropriate test for that observation. So it is not an issue of Ch-Square being over powered but misused. Correlation is the test that aligns with that statement. If that is not what you want please rephrase the questions so that others can address it.

Comment: I think we just don't get each others line of thought, nevermind? The blue bars are the empirical shares per digit and the read line indicates the progression of digit share according to Benford's law, I just don't see how one should not be able to compare these two distributions using a Chi-square test, since this is also done in various articles.

Comment: If they are used elsewhere then they are used in error. Chi squared is used to attempt to falsify the hypothesis that a difference exists between your assumed distribution and your data. What you describe in your question is the inverse, wanting to confirm that your data and your assumed hypothesis is the same. Null hypothesis testing can only be used to decide if random chance is unlikely to account for the differences. It cannot be used to prove your data is equal to your assumed distribution. An insignificant p-value would not allow you to claim the expected and actual are the same.

Comment: https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/18/help-and-how-to/statistics/equivalence-tests/supporting-topics/why-use-an-equivalence-test/, mainly discusses ttests, but the underlying purpose is the same as a chi square test, just for different data type

Comment: Well, but in this case you should just not be able to reject the null. This would not prove anything, but would fit to the observation, that the distributions are pretty similar.

Comment: Hypothesis tests prove nothing, they only quantify confidence in ONE hypothesis contrasted to the null - they can never prove the null. You need a test where the alternative hypothesis is the observed and expected are the same.

Comment: Of course, but I just would like to emphasize that most likely this is a case of a Type I error and that this is mostly caused by the large sample size. That's all I am looking for.

Comment: Does Benford's law take into account local planning regulations (e.g. sparsely populated areas often skip numbers to allow future houses to be inserted between), some developments skip the number 13, rows of houses may be demolished, leaving gaps? These are non-random events and would lead to deviation if the model does not explicitly include them. This is the kind of subtle non-random item that could be validly causing Chi-Square to be significant. I would conclude from the data you present that there is a strong association but significant effects exist that Benford's law misses.

Comment: @hannes101 This is not a type I error caused by large sample size. It is the large sample size detecting a real but tiny deviation from the null hypothesis.